# Why is gcloud app deploy uploading 0 files to google cloud storage?

Tags: gcloud

At linux I'm using Google gcloud. I notice that not always new or modified files are uploaded to the Google Cloud Storage when I use the command:

gcloud app deploy

I get the following feedback:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...done.                                             
Setting traffic split for service [default]...done.
```

The version I use is:

```
Google Cloud SDK 318.0.0
bq 2.0.62
core 2020.11.06
gsutil 4.54
```

Is there a way to force the upload of files?

Thanks,
Hans

Comment: This question will get proper attention if you open a private issue in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/), as private information is required to investigate properly. 

Does your deployment succeed? Is the new version serving traffic?

What is the output from gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug? You should edit out all private data, such as project IDs, when posting in public forums as this one.

Comment: I get this as well. I have to just make random changes until it decides that enough has changed that it will upload the file.

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this?  It is driving me nuts.

Comment: Yeah, this is ridiculous.

Comment: Same issue. Wtf Google ... great introduction to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by creating an "empty" reset project, you will find the app.yaml below. When this error occurs I select this reset project, deploy it and then I select my real project and deploy it again. That works for me.

```html
# application: reset
# version: 1
runtime: python27
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
default_expiration: "1s"

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: reset.html
  upload: reset.html
  secure: always
  http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 0):

in node.js just renamed the file name `server.js` to `app.js` and run the command `gcloud app deploy` again, its works for me!